# Comparing php value to current date and hiding content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdo

im creating  a filter function which compares dates from a database with the current date and hides content if true. so far its not fully working.

heres the code:

```
 <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="inputnew" id="filter-new" />
    <label for="filter-new">Wiedervorlagetermin</label>
</li>

<?php while($dsk=$stmk->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>

   <tr>
       <form method="post" action="kontakte.php">
     <td style="font-size:14px;">
        <p><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['timestamp']); ?></p>
        <input name="anrufe" type="date" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['timestamp']); ?>" style="display:none; padding: 0;">
     </td>
     <td style="font-size:14px;">
        <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Anrufe']); ?></p>
        <input name="anrufe" class="edit-input" type="number" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Anrufe']); ?>" style="display:none; padding: 0;">
     </td>
     <td style="font-size:14px;">
         <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Art']); ?></p>
         <input name="art" class="edit-input" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Art']); ?>" style="display:none; padding: 0;">
     </td>
     <td style="font-size:14px;">
       <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Name']); ?></p>
       <input name="name" class="edit-input" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Name']); ?>" style="display:none; padding: 0;">
     </td>
     <td style="font-size:14px;">
       <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Vorname']); ?></p>
       <input name="vorname" class="edit-input" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Vorname']); ?>" style="display:none; padding: 0;">
     </td>
     <td style="font-size:14px;">
       <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Geburtsdatum']); ?></p>
       <input name="geburtsdatum" class="edit-input" type="date" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Geburtsdatum']); ?>" style="display:none; padding: 0;">
     </td>
     <td style="font-size:14px;">
       <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Beruf']); ?></p>
       <input name="beruf" class="edit-input" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Beruf']); ?>" style="display:none; padding: 0;">
     </td>

     <td style="font-size:14px;">
       <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Info']); ?></p>
       <input name="info" class="edit-input" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Info']); ?>" style="display:none; padding: 0;">
     </td> 
    <td style="font-size:14px;">
       <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Telefon']); ?></p>
       <input name="telefon" class="edit-input" type="tel" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Telefon']); ?>" style="display:none; padding: 0;">
     </td>
    <td style="font-size:14px;">
       <p class="label-input"><?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Termin']); ?></p>
       <input name="termin" class="edit-input" type="date" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Termin']); ?>" style="display:none" id="vorlageid">
     </td>
    <td>
        <input name="prio" class="outprio" type="checkbox" <?= $dsk['Sofortkunde'] ? "checked": ""; ?>>
     </td>
     <td>
         <button  class="btn btn-danger" name="update" value="speichern" style="padding: 0;" type="submit">Speichern</button>
     </td>
         <input name="hidden" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['ID']); ?>" type="hidden">

</form>
```

thats the table created by the database. the second last column holds the date i want to compare.

and now the jquery:

```
$(function(){
$(document).on('change', '.inputnew', function(){


  if($('.inputnew').prop('checked')) {  

    var vorlage = "<?= ($dsk['Termin']); ?>";

    $.each( vorlage, function() { 
      if(vorlage != date.getdate()) {
        $('.outprio:checked').parent().parent().hide();
      }
      else {

      }
    });

    $('.outprio:not(:checked)').parent().parent().hide();  

  }
  else {
    $('.outprio').parent().parent().show(); 
  }
});
});
```

the part with hiding the non checked boxes works, but it still shows the wrong dates.
i think the problem is my variable var vorlage, if i check it in the browser console i get the following message:

```
console.log(vorlage);
```

VM5901:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: vorlage is not defined
    at :1:13

but that didnt work either. any ideas? am i on right path or is the issue something else?

Comment: In what way is it "not fully working"? Does `$('.inputnew')` exist (length > 0)? How does catching the value with PHP not work? What values/errors do you get?

Comment: I don't understand the `$.each()`: You are getting the value of a unique element, try to loop over that as if it is an array and then you do not use the values that the loop yields. What exactly is `vorlage` supposed to contain?

Comment: i edited in the filter button ("inputnew"), my bad. if i use var vorlage = "<?= ($dsk['Termin']); ?>"; instead of var vorlage =  $("#vorlageid").val(); i still get the same console readout

Comment: @AgiHammerthief the error im catchign is VM5901:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: vorlage is not defined at :1:13

Comment: @jeroen im creating a database table with <?php while($dsk=$stmk->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?> . so vorlage is supoosed to contain all the dates read out by <?= htmlspecialchars($dsk['Termin']); ?> and every date should get compared to "today"

Comment: @johannes Why don't you do the comparison with PHP and do an if statement to show data if true else....?

Comment: @AbdushSamadMiah how d i do that?